# "no appropriate default constructor available" for C++ derived class

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I got confused in C++ class definition. Can someone help me out?

I have the original template class defined as such:

```
template <typename T> 
struct SYNCHED_DATA{
    SYNCHED_DATA(int r)
    {
        var_R = r;
    }

    void set(T* pV)
    {
        var_T = *pV;
    }

    //...

private:
    //Copy constructor and assignments are NOT available!
    SYNCHED_DATA(const SYNCHED_DATA& s)
    {
    }
    SYNCHED_DATA& operator = (const SYNCHED_DATA& s)
    {
    }

    T var_T;
    int var_R;
};
```

and then I use it from another class:

```
struct THREADS_REPORT{
    THREADS_REPORT()     //error C2512: 'SYNCHED_DATA<T>' : no appropriate default constructor available
    {
    }

    void getReport(THREADS_REPORT_DATA* pOutReport)
    {
        //Retrieve report array
        sthrd.get(pOutReport);
    }
    void setReport(THREADS_REPORT_DATA* pReport)
    {
        //Set report array
        sthrd.set(pReport);
    }

private:
    SYNCHED_DATA<THREADS_REPORT_DATA> sthrd;

    //Copy constructor and assignments are NOT available!
    THREADS_REPORT(const THREADS_REPORT& s)   //error C2512: 'SYNCHED_DATA<T>' : no appropriate default constructor available
    {
    }
    THREADS_REPORT& operator = (const THREADS_REPORT& s)
    {
    }
};
```

But I get "error C2512" error at least in two spots in the second class (marked in the code above.) How do I need to change the second class to make it compile?

Comment: It means what it says. You've told it to call `SYNCHED_DATA<THREADS_REPORT_DATA>`'s default constructor and it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try initializing `THREADS_REPORT::sthrd` in the `THREADS_REPORT` constructor via the member initializer list:

```
 THREADS_REPORT(int i) : sthrd(i)
 {
 }
```

or provide a default constructor for `SYNCHED_DATA`:

```
SYNCHED_DATA() {}
```

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks. This happens due to the lack of sleep.... missed the constructor.

Comment: General rule of thumb is to explicitly define the default constructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator if you need to define any one of them. Then you don't have to guess which constructor will be emitted automatically.